AsciiDoc: Stock images for admonitions?
I'm running AsciiDoc off the Visual Studio Code support extension, and I'm trying to get admonitions with an icon, as in the examples and documentation.
Just adding :icons: to the document header looks to be not enough, as in my working directory I have no images related. I'm not trying the :icons:font, as I read that it can have issues depending on the output format, so I just stick with plain simple images (PNG or even better SVG).
Shall I manually copy some example files from the extension directory? Is there any helper function for it?
I just feel like some working examples, with usable files, would be an additional help for first-time users.

You may need to set more than just :icons:. See this page. The :iconsdir: and :icontype: and/or :imagesdir: (see also this page)

That sounds right when I'm not fit with the defaults. Anyway, my priority need is to have icons to feed it: is AsciiDoc shipped with a set of them or have I to resort to a second source?

I was directed to use :icons: font and everything worked as desired. I obtained some nice icons, without any other settings, and it resulted in compatibility both with HTML and PDF conversion.
Note that I was at first reluctant to use the font mode, as the documentation warns about possible compatibility issues. Although, I found none of them! :D
